# Get-WmiObject taking too much time to get execute

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

> Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product -ComputerName $Computer | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -match $ApplicationName}

It is taking too much time to execute approximately 20 to 30 minutes. it was working earlier, is it cause because of any windows update

Answer (score 4):

`Win32_Product` is known to be very slow because it isn't just enumerating the installed applications, but it also checks/repairs the MSI installs:

[Event log message indicates that the Windows Installer reconfigured all installed applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/974524/event-log-message-indicates-that-the-windows-installer-reconfigured-al)

Answer (score 0):

Win32_Product is broken and can be replaced by fetching it from registry directly like:

`Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\$_\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\ | ? {($_.GetValue("DisplayName")) -like "*AappName*"}`

OR if you want to have it in remote session using `Invoke-Command`, then you can do like this:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer1, Computer2 -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate }`

Note: The credentials also can be passed in the invoke-command else it will consider the windows login user. If you are doing domain wide, then you use Admin creds for this operation.

Hope it helps.